# What are some resources for learning other languages by means of Esperanto?

Tags: learning

I enjoy learning languages, and I often find that things are clearer to me when I compare them to Esperanto, than when I compare them to English. What are some language-learning resources that use Esperanto as the language of instruction? I'm most interested in Russian and Spanish, but suggestions for other languages are welcome as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it would be better suited for the "Language Learning" SE site (specifying a single language) and not Esperanto Language.

Comment: I do not think it is off-topic. It is very relevant to the Esperanto community, even if it is relevant to Language Learning as well. People who learn Esperanto want to know what they can do with it, and Esperantists are more likely to know where to find the resources requested in my question.

Comment: My concern is that the primary focus of the question is learning languages other than Esperanto, rather than being about the Esperanto language or community.

Comment: It's certainly *relevant* to Esperanto, but it's also incredibly broad.  There are likely at least dozens of such resources, and many more coming out all the time.  See [Should this site allow open-ended resource questions?](http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/24/9)

Comment: @Nathaniel the number of such resources seemed rather limited to me, at least I never have an easy time finding them...

Comment: I would say it is off-topic because it is asking for a list of off-site resources. Such kind of question are questions that would need to be constantly updated every time a resource is not available anymore, or a new resource is available. Apart that, users will up-vote the answers without basing on an objective criterion.

Comment: Well, don't most questions and answers involve off-site resources? And wouldn't that be the same on Language Learning? But whatever, if you close it here I'll just have to continue searching myself...

Comment: The difference is that for other questions, the answer  is in this site; they aren't just a link to another site. Stack Exchange doesn't aim to be a repository of links, but a repository of knowledge. Also, the problem with links is that they need to be kept updated, to be useful. If a site goes off, the answer suggesting it should be edited; if other sites come out, a new answer should be added.

Answer (score 6):

I know the websites [Slovake.eu](http://slovake.eu) and [Deutsch.info](http://deutsch.info) that have been translated to Esperanto.

Comment: Also [Russky.info](http://russky.info/).

Answer (score 5):

Here one can learn Toki Pona through Esperanto: http://tokipona.info/

Answer (score 5):

There are several conversation guides from national languages to learn Esperanto, and it's able to use most of the content in both directions. For instance, I have these:

- **[Italian]** Parlo esperanto: manuale di conversazione (Davide Astori, 1996)
- **[Catalan]** Guia de conversa català-esperanto: breu introducció a la llengua i al moviment (Pedro M. Martín Burutxaga, 2016)

Answer (score 5):

You said you're interested in Russian. Here's a link to learn **Russian idioms** through **Esperanto**:
http://www.russievirtuelle.com/locutions/index.htm

> ГОЛОДНЫЙ КАК ВОЛК
>
> [golodnij kak volk]
>
> Malsata kiel lupo.
>
> Esti tre malsatega.
>
> **Malsata kiel lupo (hundo).**

Vi diris, ke vi ŝatus lerni la Rusan. Jen ligilo por lerni **rusajn idiomaĵojn** per **Esperanto**.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book called "Esenca lernolibro de la itala lingvo", published shortly before the Universala Kongreso in Florence in 2006. I think that there have been similar publications related to the language of the country of the Universala Kongreso in other years too.

Comment: Recommendable. It has a high quality, like when you get a book to learn foreign languages in Spanish or English (in fact, it's a translation). During my reading, I had the feeling that maybe it'd be more useful if I'd have got it in Spanish because of the language proximity, but it was cool to learn through Esperanto. My teacher told me that after reading it I had a noticeable better Italian.

Answer (score 4):

On Telegram, there's over 20 bilingual groups (Esperanto + another language) which were originally intended for beginners to learn Esperanto, but many experienced Esperanto speakers also use them to ask questions in Esperanto about their target language, so it sometimes feels like a group tandem chat. I personally have used the [Esperanto-Svenska group](https://telegram.me/joinchat/AGedCz61jc-fOmUffBtM6A) to ask questions about Swedish and received very helpful explanations. You can find the complete list of Esperanto Telegram groups on [telegramo.org](http://www.telegramo.org/).

Answer (score 3):

A good article about this is http://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/language-learning-through-esperanto/  One resource listed there that no one's pointed out yet is the Chinese site  http://esperanto.cri.cn/everydaychinese/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

On Italki or similar platforms, you can search people with a solid Esperanto knowledge and ask them to teach you a language per Esperanto.

Example: [French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVwdqqIZ4UQ&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 2):

[Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) has a **Spanish->Esperanto Tree** which you can use as a reverse tree to gain familiarity with Spanish if you know Esperanto. While it may be more common to use a reverse tree after using a forward tree to your target language, you can always combine a reverse tree with other resources or switch back and forth between the **English->Spanish** and **Spanish->Esperanto** trees.

Answer (score 0):

I’m constructing an Esperanto-hosted [Encyclopedia Dictionary of Mercan English](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/). I link to mostly English-language resources, but also to the Esperanto version of Wiktionary, and I often make comments, in Esperanto, about points in English. You can access the dictionary here: http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the basics of Japanese with the book *Enkonduko en la japanan* of Yamasaki Seikô. You can buy it at [UEA's Library](http://katalogo.uea.org/?inf=6254).